# slow insert into the android database

Tags: android, sqlite, insert

I have to insert the following fields in android database:

**this code is in my activity**

```
for(int k=0; k<pdvs.size(); k++)
      {
       Map<String, String> testMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
       testMap1.put("pos_id", pdvs.get(k).pos_id);
       testMap1.put("visit_date", pdvs.get(k).nextvisitDate);
       testMap1.put("roadmap_id", String.valueOf(roadmap_id));
       testMap1.put("sys_visit_status_id", "1");
       testMap1.put("gps_latitude", "5");
       testMap1.put("gps_longitude", "5");

      db.insertData("pos_visit", testMap1);
```

}

There are about 16 rows to insert...not that much. Still I tried to use a `ContentValues` like this:
**this is the code from SQLiteOpenHelper class**

```
public long insertData(String tableName, Map<String, String> map) {
            long id;
        ContentValues columnValues = new ContentValues();

            db.beginTransaction();
            try{

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            String columnName = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            columnValues.put(columnName, value);

        }
        id = db.insert(tableName, null, columnValues);

            db.setTransactionSuccessful();
            }finally{
                db.endTransaction();
            }
            return id;
    }
```

but it still takes about 10-12 seconds to introduce 16 rows.  Anyway, after that I found out about `InsertHelper` as known to be much faster and I did this:

```
 public long insertData(String tableName, Map<String, String> map) {
            long id = 0;
            int i = 0;
            int [] columnIndex = new int[map.size()];
            String [] value = new String[map.size()];

        InsertHelper ih = new InsertHelper(db, tableName);

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {

            String columnName = entry.getKey();
                    columnIndex[i] = ih.getColumnIndex(columnName);
            value[i] = entry.getValue();
                    i++;
        }

            try{
            ih.prepareForInsert();
        for (int k=0; k<columnIndex.length; k++) {

             ih.bind(columnIndex[k], value[k]);
        }
                 id = ih.execute();
            }finally{
            ih.close();
            }

            return id;
    }
```

But the result is that this second method is as slow as the first one!!! Anyone can give me an idea about how to improve the speed of insert into my database? What I'm doing wrong in these methods?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your outer loop in a transaction and get rid of it in your insertData method.

Right now, you call a full chain of open transaction, insert, set success for each element of your pdvs set. If pdvs must always be persisted as a whole, then you should only use 1 transaction for the whole operation. It'll make your code noticeably faster.

```
// begin transaction here
for(int k=0; k<pdvs.size(); k++)
                    {
                        Map<String, String> testMap1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    testMap1.put("pos_id", pdvs.get(k).pos_id);
                    testMap1.put("visit_date", pdvs.get(k).nextvisitDate);
                    testMap1.put("roadmap_id", String.valueOf(roadmap_id));
                    testMap1.put("sys_visit_status_id", "1");
                    testMap1.put("gps_latitude", "5");
                    testMap1.put("gps_longitude", "5");

                    db.insertData("pos_visit", testMap1);

                    }
//set success here
```

And in your insertData just use insert without transaction

Comment: Maybe, but the code listed above by you its in my activity not inside my SQLiteOpenHelper class. So I don't have directt acces to db instance. so I cannot call db.beginTransaction() outside SQLiteOpenHelper class. Understand?

Comment: I would say, that it's a design flaw by your side, and you should refactor it to be able to wrap batch operations in one transaction.

Comment: ok, thank you. I will try to do that in lack of other better way

Comment: You should try to write a test version of it, even if it's a dirty crude hack and exposing some encapsulated data (like db instance), to check if it's really worth it. Maybe you won't actually win anything by it.

Comment: its better, but still there is still to go

Comment: Well, I can also suggest some micro optimizations. You should avoid new allocations, but you allocate new hashmap for each item in your outer loop (maybe create 1 and reuse it). There are also some minor things like pdvs.size() in for statement. It is a good practice to assign to some int variable this size and use variable, so it won't call method on each iteration (minus some minuscule overhead). You can also to find a way to do it with just one loop instead of inner loops, also small gain.